# Prevent elements with a nav class from collapsing

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am building my page layout using bootstrap 3x. Even though it's most popular because it's `mobile first` the smallest device that is targeted by this application will be a laptop with standard `1366x768` (if I'm not mistaken) resolution and above.

Is bootstrap the best solution in this case is out of question since I'm not the one picking the technologies.

So what I do now is removing all unneeded classes from my markup and also I change the behavior to what I think is more native for a standard web site.

I changed my navigation bar like so :

```
   <div role="navigation">
      <div class="container second-navigation-container">
          <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

But still when the display size gets small enough (resizing the window) I get this

[image: Collpasing menu]

which I understand is desired behavior for devices with small displays, but what I want is just to shrink the elements to some point like it's happening right now and then start cutting off the side. Something like this :

[image: Overlayed menu]

I've already made some customizations to the default bootstrap css but for this one I'm not sure what to look for and how to change it to get what I want.